# On linux: cp: missing destination file operand after source file

Tags: perl

Below code is the part of the script, in which I am merging files of different directories. After merging I am copying remaining files into final directory.
Merging is working fine but while copying files I am getting

```
cp: missing destination file operand after `/users/abc/perl_scripts/temp_dir/b.cc'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
sh: line 1: /users/abc/perl_scripts/temp: is a directory
```

```
for $k(dir1) {
     $flag=0;
     for $j(@dir2) {
          if("$k" eq "$j") {
               &merge_gcov("$UERRC1/$k","$UERRC2/$k","$DATA_DIR/$k");
               $flag=1;
               last;                            
          }
     }
     if($flag == 0) {
           #print ">>>>>>>>>>>>> cp $UERRC1/$k $DATA_DIR/$k \n";
           'cp $UERRC1/$k,$DATA_DIR`;
     }
 }
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this...

Comment: Your indentation is terrible. It looks like you're using global variables everywhere. Are you using `warnings` and `strict`? Don't call subs with `&`. Your `cp` line is a syntax error (show your real code). Don't use backticks in void context. Post a complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Its just part of the script... Complete code is too big...Problem is with cp command not with subs.. I corrected 'cp $UERRC1/$k $DATA_DIR`;

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `dir1` (a bareword) in your for loop arguments? If you are not using `use warnings` that will be a silent bug where the loop runs once, and `$k` is the string `"dir1"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you are using system calls you are most likely doing something redundant, and it certainly is redundant in this case. Perl is very capable of copying files. I recommend the [`File::Copy`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy) module, which is a core module in perl 5. Using it is simple:

```
use File::Copy qw(copy);
copy $from, $to or die $!;   # it is a good idea to check if the copy failed
```

Also, instead of looping over all the file names in `@dir2` and see if the name matches the one in `$k`, why not just check if the file exists in the other directory? E.g.

```
if (-e "$UERRC1/$k") {    # check if file exists
    merge_gcov("$UERRC1/$k", "$UERRC2/$k", "$DATA_DIR/$k"); 
} else { 
    copy "$UERRC1/$k", $DATA_DIR or die $!; 
}
```

The documentation for the file test `-e` is found in [`perldoc -f "-X"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

You really should use variable names that are more appropriate. It will make your code more readable and much easier to maintain and debug.

Also...

Before you do anything else, you should add the following two lines to your script and fix the errors that undoubtedly appear:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

`strict` will force you to declare all variables (typically with `my $foo`) which will remove hard to detect bugs due to typos in variable names. The error message will read "Global symbol $foo requires explicit package name ...".

`warnings` will give you information about things that you are doing wrong. This is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments to cp are of the form `cp from to`, but you have `cp from,to`.

This may be why it complains about the number of arguments - `$UERRC1/$k,$DATA_DIR` is a *single* argument. It should be `cp $UERRC1/$k $DATA_DIR`, like in your print statement.

Comment: So update your question to show the real code (specifically the cp line), and un-comment that print statement to confirm all the variables are what you expect.